# Laravel 5.4 - error when vendor:publish executed command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4, vendor

I just installed Laravel 5.4.* and I have error when I execute this command:

**php artisan vendor:publish**

```
vagrant@homestead:~/projects/xxxx_com$ php artisan vendor:publish


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'League\Flysystem\MountManager' not found


vagrant@homestead:~/projects/xxxx_com$
```

Have you got an idea?

Comment: It's a fresh installation of Laravel 5.4.*

Comment: What package you utilize within this project? `graham-campbell/flysystem` or `league/flysystem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you added new package to `composer.json` but you haven't run `composer install`. So make sure you run:

```
composer install
```

and after that run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update your composer, run `composer update`
and see if that help.